# Angular MouseClick event

Tags: javascript, angular, mouseevent

I'm having quite often the same issue as [this discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18244#issuecomment-316597505) described.

I'm not able to reproduce the situation (since it usually happens in a complicated project), but the environment can be shorten as the code below:

```
<input id="input1" type="text" [(ngModel)]="value1" />
<button id="button1" type="button" (click)="onClick()">Button</button>
```

```
onClick() {
  console.log('click');
}
```

However, as the `#input1` is focused, and I try to click `#button1`, it doesn't trigger the `onClick()` function until the second click.

I have found some other ways that sometimes help to fix this problem: such as using `NgZone`, or change `(click)` into `(mousedown)`.  However, I would like to know why this happen?  Is there something I can keep in mind to avoid such situation during the development?

In [the discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18244#issuecomment-316597505), I've seen they're talking about that `mouseup` never been registered according to the view change, but I don't really understand it, so I recompose the question again, hope to know more about the problem.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Angular's click is one of the most basic example suggested by the official tutorials, I doubt there is any issue with zone.js here, there rather is **something else** not working in your code. Can you please provide a larger portion of it? out of the box, your example, should work as expected, unless onClick is private or protected in your component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This one

```
<button (click)="myMouseClicked($event)">Mouse Click</button>
```

> Than Your App component

```
 export class AppComponent {

      myMouseClicked(event) {
        console.log(event);
        alert("Mouse Clicked");
      }

    }
```